# Training Stanford NER failed

Tags: java, classification, stanford-nlp

I'm still new to the recognition process and still trying to learn more about it.
I have a project where I need to recognize: Table names, People, Departments.
I tried using Stanford NER with it's 3 class and it did recognize people names.
For the department names I tried to train the NER to recognize the departments as organizations. As I found no result on how to create a new annotation for them.
I did follow the instruction from their website.
First I did create a txt file with the following content:

> Ahmad works in Customer Service department. The department name is
>   Customer Service. It has started in 1997, it was called Customer
>   Service since then. Customer Service has one manager and many
>   employees. The number of Customer Service department is 1122D. Ahmad
>   works in Development department. The department name is Development.
>   It has started in 1997, it was called Development since then.
>   Development has one manager and many employees. The number of
>   Development department is 1122D. Ahmad works in Finance department.
>   The department name is Finance. It has started in 1997, it was called
>   Finance since then. Finance has one manager and many employees. The
>   number of Finance department is 1122D. Ahmad works in Human Resources
>   department. The department name is Human Resources. It has started in
>   1997, it was called Human Resources since then. Human Resources has
>   one manager and many employees. The number of Human Resources
>   department is 1122D. Ahmad works in Marketing department. The
>   department name is Marketing. It has started in 1997, it was called
>   Marketing since then. Marketing has one manager and many employees.
>   The number of Marketing department is 1122D.

Then I used these commands:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer corpus.txt > corpus.tok

perl -ne 'chomp; print "$_\tO\n"' corpus.tok > corpus.tsv 

java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop corpus.prop
```

Then I got the following error:

```
CRFClassifier invoked on Mon Dec 01 09:38:10 AST 2014 with arguments:
   -prop corpus.prop
argsToProperties could not read properties file: null
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "corpus.prop" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.argsToProperties(StringUtils.java:879)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.argsToProperties(StringUtils.java:818)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:2869)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "corpus.prop" as either class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:448)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.argsToProperties(StringUtils.java:866)
    ... 2 more
```

How can I train the classier properly?

Many Thanks

UPDATE: 
Here is my .prop file

```
#location of the training file
trainFile = /Users/ha/stanford-ner-2014-10-26/corpus.tsv
#location where you would like to save (serialize to) your
#classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
#making it faster and smaller
serializeTo = dept-model.ser.gz

#structure of your training file; this tells the classifier
#that the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in
#column 1
map = word=0,answer=1

#these are the features we'd like to train with
#some are discussed below, the rest can be
#understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
#no ngrams will be included that do not contain either the
#beginning or end of the word
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
#the next 4 deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

Comment: Have you created `corpus.prop` / are you pointing to the correct path? It looks like the `CRFClassifier` is failing to find that file.

Comment: I have edit my answer and add prop file.

Comment: Try giving an absolute path to this `corpus.prop` on the command line. It looks like the relative path lookup is failing.

Comment: Works now, Thanks. How can I use it in my code if I'm already using another classifier? String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

Comment: You provided a relative path in that `corpus.prop` file to which the model should be saved (property name `serializeTo`). Provide the path to that same file in your Java code.